Close popup when user presses the browser back button

If I open any page (say home page) then we go to another page (say
product detail page).
In PDP (product detail page), we are showing a popup when user click
add to cart button.
So once popup is visible and then user presses the browser back
button then it closed the popup instead of going back to previous
page which home page in this case.

In the above case, code is working fine as expected.

But If user directly open PDP page (example like user copied the URL
of PDP page and open in new tab), and presses the add to cart button,
popup will be visible, but now if the user presses the browser back
button, then it is going back to previous page. This should not
happen.

I think it is because there are no items in history. so problem occured.
Note: I just want that, if popup is open and user presses the browser back button, it should close the popup instead of going back to previous page.
I am using ReactJS.
Please help here!
/**
 * If user pressed back button but add to cart popup dialog is open then
 * close the popup dialog
 * instead of going back to the previous page.
 */
useEffect(() => {
    const unblock = history.block((location, action) => {
        const element = document.getElementById("quickviewPopup");
        let isPopupOpen = element.classList.contains("root_open");
        console.log("", product, isPopupOpen);
        if(!isPopupOpen){
            // Recheck popup open from home page.
            const items = document.querySelectorAll(".newArrivalProduct");
            isPopupOpen = [...items].find(i=>i.querySelector(".root_open"));
        }

        if (product && isPopupOpen) {
            closeQuickView();
            /**
             * If we don't use history.goForward() then popup closed and we are on same page. But URL changes.
             * URL should also NOT change. So we have to use history.goForward();
             */
            history.goForward();
            return false; // Prevent navigation
        }
    });

    return () => {
        unblock();
    };
}, [product, closeQuickView, history]);

